# Angular.js chart redraws when clicking on angular-bootstrap-dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-chart

I'm having a issue with `angular-chartjs` that is driving me mad.

I have a bootstrap dropdown (using `angular-ui-bootstrap`) next to a , used by `angular-chartjs`.

When the chart has more than 7 items in it's data source, clicking the dropdown makes the chart redraw once. I can't find an explanation to why this is happening.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vz4qhqpw/378/

Go to second tab and click in the dropdown. The chart will redraw. Now go to the javascript code and change the last line to call `updateData2()` instead of `updateData()`, and the issue is gone. Adding more than 7 items to an array in `updateData2()` makes the issue happen as well.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing chart-colors explicitly for each chart (e.g. generate an array of random colors and pass it to each chart):

```
<!-- added chart-colors attribute -->
<canvas class="chart chart-base"
    chart-options="categories[heading].options"
    chart-type="categories[heading].chartType"
    chart-data="categories[heading].data"
    chart-labels="categories[heading].labels"
    chart-colors="categories[heading].colors"
    height="130">
</canvas>
```

See my corrected version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s8pe2rrf/2/

---

**Explanation:**

Looking at angular-chart.js source code, you may see that the directive adds watch for each attribute, including chart-colors

```
scope.$watch('chartColors', watchOther, true);
```

and recreates chart when an attribute value is changed.

If you don't specify colors initially, default colors array is used, which contains 7 items (**this is where the magic 7 comes from!**):

```
Chart.defaults.global.colors = [
  '#97BBCD', // blue
  '#DCDCDC', // light grey
  '#F7464A', // red
  '#46BFBD', // green
  '#FDB45C', // yellow
  '#949FB1', // grey
  '#4D5360'  // dark grey
];
```

And when your chart has more than 7 items, chart.js internally adds additional colors as necessary. 
Looks like this triggers the listener that is mentioned above.

**But why does it happen on selecting a dropdown?**
Chart.js is not a native Angular library (it's used through "proxy", angular-chart.js), so seems like 
the directive is not aware that new values are being added to colors array, so the listener is triggered 
only when $apply is called next time, which happens to be a click on dropdown.

Comment: Just realized that while the fiddle seems working, my answer definitely lacks explanation, will add some.

Comment: Added explanation

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Very good explanation - would never think of this solution, though the 7 default color is a good clue of what was going on.